# JavaScript - convert Hours to minutes (universal format (12 and 24))

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Maybe anyone know is it possible easy convert hours (like in American 12/h (AM,PM) and European 24/h format ) to minutes?

Maybe someone did this stuff?

for Example from (00:00):

22:22 -> to minutes

AM 6:02 - to minutes

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can use momentjs for this application.

Parse, validate, manipulate, and display dates in JavaScript.
http://momentjs.com/

Comment: It's nice plugin but i didn't find how to reach solution.

Comment: Solved with .duration().asMinutes(); But if format will be 12/h?